# Ejecutar un programa Java en una Raspberry

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

Tengo un programa desarrollado en Java y quiero saber si es posible ejecutarlo en una raspberry, ya que necesito conectarlo a una pantalla y que el programa se ejecute todo el día, no se si es posible algo así... el programa trabaja en modo de pantalla completa.

Se puede instalar un desktop de Java en una raspberry? Y si es posible de qué manera se hace?, he buscado pero aún no encuentro una buena explicación.

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Los lenguajes principales que se usan para programar en Raspberry Pi son

1. Python
2. C

Pero al parecer existen muchas opciones. Si programas en Java necesitas  http://pi4j.com/

> This project is intended to provide a friendly object-oriented I/O API
>   and implementation libraries for Java Programmers to access the full
>   I/O capabilities of the Raspberry Pi platform. This project abstracts
>   the low-level native integration and interrupt monitoring to enable
>   Java programmers to focus on implementing their application business
>   logic.a

**Traducción:**
El objetivo de este proyecto es proporcionar una API de E / S orientada a objetos y bibliotecas de implementación para los programadores de Java para acceder a todas las capacidades de E / S de la plataforma Raspberry Pi. Este proyecto resume la integración nativa de bajo nivel y el monitoreo de interrupciones para permitir que los programadores de Java se centren en la implementación de la lógica empresarial de su aplicación.

Links:
http://www.rmnd.net/building-an-action-camera-using-a-raspberry-pi-and-java/

Answer (score 0):

Se puede instalar Java en la Raspberri Pi
Según indica en la Documentación.

Para instalar el java de Oracle:
Runtime Eviroment:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jre
```

Java Development Kit:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
```

---

También puedes instalar el Openjdk (que es un Java de código abierto)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```